# OpenLDAP ACL order

Tags: acl, openldap

I have 3 ACL's in slapd.conf file.

```
1. access to attrs=userPassword
    filter="(&(objectClass=customAttributes)(!(statusCode=A)))"
    by * none

2. access to attrs=userPassword
    filter="(&(objectClass=customAttributes)(statusCode=A))"
    by self =wx
    by * =x

3. access to dn.subtree="dc=mycompany,dc=com"
    by self write
    by group.exact="cn=administrators,dc=mycompany,dc=com" write
    by group.exact="cn=applications,dc=mycompany,dc=com" read
    by * auth
```

The purpose of ACL 1 and 2 is to disable any user whose status code is other than A.  It works fine.  The purpose of ACL 3 is to make `member` of `administrators` group as admin and `member` of `applications` group to have read only access.  Everyone else must authenticate.

If I have ACL's in above order then for ACL 3, I cannot read/edit `userPassword` field of any user using admin account.  If I have ACL 3 before 1 and 2 then ACL 1 and 2 are not working.

Is there any particular order for ACL that I need to follow?  Can these 3 ACL's be consolidated into one ACL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change ACL 2 as follows

```
2. access to attrs=userPassword
    filter="(&(objectClass=customAttributes)(statusCode=A))"
    by self =wx
    by group.exact="cn=administrators,dc=mycompany,dc=com" write
    by * =x
```

Reason: Earlier ACL 3 was not executed as I had everything else have read only permission in ACL 2 (`by * =x`).

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't very DRY (do not repeat yourself) and I have been looking for confirmation of this in any of the documentation.  Processing stops as soon as the "what" clause in an "access" entry matches (all subsequent access entries are consequently ignored).  This is not intuitive.